# (Unreal Engine 4) Is there a way I can convert a skeletal mesh pose to a static mesh at runtime?

Tags: unreal-engine4, skeletal-animation, skeletal-mesh

I'm aware that there's a way to convert a skeletal mesh to a static mesh by right clicking on it and clicking on the convert option. I was wondering if there's a way I can do that at runtime. I have some functions that only work with static meshes and I have some cool ideas I can do with my game if I can get this functionality.

My final goal is to be able to get a snapshot of a specific animation frame of the skeletal mesh, and then create a new static mesh based on the pose in this animation frame.

I have looked into the pose snapshot tool, but that seems to only work for applying a certain pose to the animator rather than create a static mesh with the pose.